# Where can Java classes be defined?

Tags: java, class, definition

There are many places in Java where a class can be defined. It can be public, static, anonymous, etc.

I know there are a bunch of them. Does someone have a complete list of all the types of class that one can come across in Java?

Comment: You will want to read the [JLS Chapter 8: Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html)

Comment: You also have nested classes and method local classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to read the [JLS Chapter 8: Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html):

> ClassModifiers:
>
> ```
> ClassModifier
>
> ClassModifiers ClassModifier
> ```
>
> ClassModifier: one of
>
> ```
> Annotation public protected private
>
> abstract static final strictfp
> ```

But you will also want to note that

> The access modifier public (§6.6) pertains only to top level classes (§7.6) and to member classes (§8.5), not to local classes (§14.3) or anonymous classes (§15.9.5).
>
> The access modifiers protected and private (§6.6) pertain only to member classes within a directly enclosing class or enum declaration (§8.5).
>
> The modifier static pertains only to member classes (§8.5.1), not to top level or local or anonymous classes.

If you need more detail, please read section 8.1, it deals with the class declaration (which you are likely interested in).

Answer (score 2):

- Outer i.e. non - nested classes can be applied with public and
  default modifiers
- Nested classes can be static
- Inner classes can be private, protected, default and public.
- All classes can be marked as abstract or final
- An abstract class can never be final and final class can never be abstract

  ```
  public class ClassModifier {

  /* a private class */
  private class PrivateInnerClass {

  }

  /* static nested class */
  public static class StaticNestedClass {

  }

  public void methodForInnerClass() {
  /* A class declared inside a method */
  class MethodLocalInnerClass {

  }

  }

  }
  ```

Well in a much simpler way, you can simply open eclipse IDE, create a new class and play around with all the available options and create some classes.